# ignored counting the same integers

Tags: python

I am very new at Python.
I need to input integers, and sort integers into positive and negative lists.
When the input is 0, it can be ignored.
The result should look like this:

```
input integers:
23 -2 5 89 -43 0 5 0
positive: 4, negative: 2, sum: 77

input integers:

there is no input
positive: 0, negative: 0, sum: 77
```

This is my code, but it has some problems.

```
L = [int(x) for x in input("input integers: \n").split()]
positive=[]; negative=[]


for number in L:
    if L==[]:
        print("There is no input")

    if L!=[]:
        if number > 0:
            positive.append(number)
        elif number < 0 :
            negative.append(number)

        else:
            break
print("positive: %d , negative : %d, total : %d" %(len(positive), len(negative), sum(L)))
```

first of all, my code doesn't count the same numbers twice;
in this case, there are two '5', but it counts as one.

second, when there is no input number,
    print("There is no input")
is not shown.

How should I solve these problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> first of all, my code doesn't count the same numbers twice; in this case, there are two '5', but it counts as one.

Not precisely. What's happening is that, as soon as your loop encounters a zero, it `break`s out of the loop and stops looking at any further numbers. In the case of your first input, this means it ends up skipping over the second `5`.

The solution is simple: remove the `else: break`. It's unnecessary. If a number is neither `> 0` nor `< 0`, you don't need to do anything, so you don't need an `else:` for that case.

> second, when there is no input number, print("There is no input") is not shown.

The check for an empty list is inside the `for` loop. If the list is empty, there are no numbers to iterate over, so the loop never runs.

Move that check outside the loop.

---

As an aside, there's a much simpler way of doing the job of your `for` loop:

```
positive = [x for x in L if x > 0]
negative = [x for x in L if x < 0]
```

This implementation uses [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). You will probably learn about these later.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind explanations!!

Comment: @EunseoSong If an answer solves your problem, [you should accept the answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)